# Is there a way to enable popup in every browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, popupwindow

I am creating a script which generates popups. But most of the browsers blocks popups by default. I want to open popup on my domain without blocking popups.

```
var pop = window.open('about:blank', 'new_window_123', 'height=150,width=150');

// Detect pop blocker
setTimeout(function() {
if(!pop || pop.closed || pop.closed == 'undefined' || pop == 'undefined' || parseInt(pop.innerWidth) == 0 || pop.document.documentElement.clientWidth != 150 || pop.document.documentElement.clientHeight != 150){
pop && pop.close();
alert('Popups must be enabled.');
}else{
alert('Popups is enabled.');
pop && pop.close();
}}, 1000);
```

This script tell me popup enable/disable. Is there a way to  turn off popup blocker on browser and run popup

Comment: You can tell the user to enable popups if this is something that's integral to your website, but the answer to your question is no.

Comment: Most sites just show a message like "It appears you're using a pop-up blocker, please disable the blocker for this site to work properly" or something along those lines.

Comment: In my experience, most browsers only block popups if a website sends up a popup more than ~4 times on one page. Users can re-enable if they noticed that they need it.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to turn off the popup blocker via javascript.  If there was, then all scripts that do popups would just do that and the popup blocker would be of no use.  In most browsers, there is a way for the end-user to allow popup blockers for the current site, but it is something you would have to instruct the end-user to do, not something your page can do itself.

Some popup blockers will allow a popup window if it is opened in direct response to a user click (e.g. the popup window is opened from within a click handler).

An easier way around the problem (for some kinds of content) is to stop using popup windows and instead use an overlay div that floats above your content in the same window as that is not blocked by the popup blocker.

Comment: ok, but i created a javascript in which i added a loop to open multiple window on load/onclick. First window open without blocking in every browser others are blockes. What is the reason.

Comment: i want to popup new windows just like farecompare.com

Comment: @Burhan - Opening multiple popup windows is blocked because browsers and users consider that to be undesirable behavior (and I would agree).

Comment: yes but there are large companies like kayak and farecompare is doing this and showing result in popup windows. I just want to know what am i missing. I just want to enable popup on my domain only. If you know the method tell me, otherwise there is no need to discuss this anymore. I asked a question to help build me code but so far no results.

Comment: @Burhan - I told you how to open ONE popup window (opened directly via a user event).  That's what I think is possible.  I'm not holding anything back here.  But if I personally browsed to a site that opened multiple popup windows at once, I would never go back to that site again.

Comment: have you tried kayak and farecompare, if not then try, these sites are one of the largest frs system in the world. Go on one of these site and search for flight/hotel and then you can see what i am talking about. Please go to these site and then you can have an idea which type of popup i am talking about

Comment: @Burhan - I told you what I know.  I'm not going to go reverse-engineer those sites.  If you care to, then go do it yourself.  I personally hate what kayak does and don't use that site.  It sounds like you're mad at me for not doing reverse engineering for you.  I told you what I know.  I will not be continuing this conversation.